# While typing, does not change the value of my ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying, as I type over the text field, to reflect what I'm writing inside a  tag.
For some strange reason, nothing appears. I think this is by the directive. I am using in my real project version 1.6.2 of angular, and it appears inside the tag  the text "false". (I do not know how to put this version into jsdfiddle.). In my real project I'm using a very large directive, so for this example I want to find a solution without removing my directive.

```
<section ng-app="app">
 <article ng-controller="appCtrl" class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal well" name="form" >
     <input type="text"  ng-model="mytext"  class="form-control" validate />
     <center>typping the text {{mytext}}</center>
     <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" >SEND</button>
    </form>
</article>
</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmmj1nfv/

Comment: Return `val` at the end of the `$parser`. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmmj1nfv/1/)

Comment: The Problem with your directive, please follow this link http://jsfiddle.net/kmmj1nfv/7/ and type "manuel" inside the text box. the button will enable. or  if you enable for any text then follow this link  http://jsfiddle.net/kmmj1nfv/8/